# query date time picker not get date in another function call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please explain What is error here,and why i get undefined in second alert in loadchart function call?

I have problem with facing date from date timepicker..I also used bootstrap here

Here is ny code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jchartfx.css" />
<link href="Styles/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jchartfx.system.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jchartfx.coreBasic.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jchartfx.animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

End Date:
        
        
    
    
        Start Date:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

    var chart1;
    var startDate;
    var endDate;        

        $('#dp2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $('.span2').change();
        });

        $('.span2').change(function () {
            startDate = $(this).val();
            alert(startDate);                

        });

        $('#dp1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $('.span1').change();

        });

        $('.span1').change(function () {
            endDate = $(this).val();
            alert(endDate);
            loadChart();

        });

        function loadChart(startDate, endDate) {

            chart1 = new cfx.Chart();
            chart1.getAnimations().getLoad().setEnabled(true);
            chart1.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Pie);

            alert(startDate);
            alert(endDate);

            //startDate = '11/20/2013';
            //endDate = '11/26/2013';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ("Default2.aspx/GetData"),
                data: "{startDate:'" + startDate + "',endDate:'" + endDate + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    var data = $.parseJSON(result.d);

                    chart1.setDataSource(data);
                    var divHolder = document.getElementById('ChartDiv');
                    chart1.create(divHolder);

                },
                error: function (xhr, txt, err) {
                    alert("error connecting to data: " + txt);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: That's because you are accepting `endDate` and `startDate` as parameters to the `loadChart` method. This creates a local copy of `endDate` & `startDate` variables. Just delete the arguments expected by the function and you should be good to go.

Comment: hi thanks for answer srvikram, but i have to pass this two date in loadchart so when i change end date then i have to load this chart...If i remove argument from function then how can i pass this two date as well?

Comment: Hi,check out my answer below.

Comment: Superb man..Its look good and working...but it show more than on time chart when second calls(end date change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify your code as shown below.

```
var chart1;      

    $('#dp2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        loadChart();
    });

    $('#dp1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
       loadChart();
    });
    function loadChart() {

        chart1 = new cfx.Chart();
        chart1.getAnimations().getLoad().setEnabled(true);
        chart1.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Pie);

        var startDate = $("#dp2 input").val();
        var endDate = $("#dp1 input").val();

        alert(startDate);
        alert(endDate);

        //startDate = '11/20/2013';
        //endDate = '11/26/2013';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ("Default2.aspx/GetData"),
            data: "{startDate:'" + startDate + "',endDate:'" + endDate + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                var data = $.parseJSON(result.d);

                chart1.setDataSource(data);
                var divHolder = document.getElementById('ChartDiv');
                chart1.create(divHolder);

            },
            error: function (xhr, txt, err) {
                alert("error connecting to data: " + txt);
            }
        });
    }
```